# strstr valgrind error

Tags: c, valgrind, strstr

I need some help with `char*` initialization and `strstr` in C. This is the general issue:

I have a function `func1`

func1() func2();

The issue is that valgrind gives an error basically saying that strstr might be using an uninitialized value. To rectify this, I'd have to do something like `char* str = "hello world";`, but then I can't `realloc`, which is an issue.

I have tested my program with random strings and the issue is the fact that valgrind is treating `str` as uninitialized, but I just don't know how to initialize it without getting rid of the ability to realloc. Any suggestions?

The error is:

```
==14356== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14356==    at 0x4C29313: strstr (in path)
==14356==    by 0x401983: func2 (in path)
==14356==    by 0x401B06: func1 (in path)
==14356==    by 0x4013D7: main (in path)
==14356== 
==14358== Syscall param execve(argv[i]) points to uninitialised byte(s)
 at 0x4ECFCB7: execve (in path)
==14308==    by 0x4E6A76C: do_system (in path)
==14308==    by 0x4013ED: main
```

Edited: Added in the actual functions, changed names and such.

Comment: Could you tell with which arguments you call func1 and func2?

Comment: Not enough information. Show the code that calls func2.

Comment: Sorry, I updated. The last line in func1 should be `str = func2(path, str);`. The code that calls func1 is `char* cmd = func1(&i, len, arr, path);`, where `i` is a valid integer, `len` is a valid length for `arr`, `arr` is an array of strings, and `path` is a single string.

Answer (score 0):

In your `func1` you have the following:

```
        str = realloc(str, (stringLen + currExpLen) * sizeof(char)+2);
        sprintf(str, "%s %s", str, currExp);
```

Using the same string on both sides of `sprintf` is probably a bad idea.  As the output is written its going to clobber the input (`str`) which could result in any manner of unexpected behaviors.  `realloc` takes care of whatever copying might be needed, so your sprintf could be replaced by some strcats:

```
        str = realloc(str, (stringLen + currExpLen) * sizeof(char)+2);
        strcat(str, " ");
        strcat(str, currExp);
```

Comment: That's a great suggestion and I've implemented it, so thank you for that, but it's not my issue. From what I understand, the issue is that valgrind thinks `strstr()` is being passed uninitialized values, but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is your problem:

In func2:

```
    str = realloc(str, (stringLen + pathLen+1)*sizeof(char));

    memmove(&str[rplcIndx + pathLen], &str[rplcIndx+2], stringLen-rplcIndx-2);
    memcpy(&str[rplcIndx], path, pathLen);
```

The `memmove` doesn't copy the null terminator (it is at position `stringLen`, but the last byte copied would be `rpcIndx+2+stringLen-rpcIndx-2-1 = stringLen-1` (remember `src[len]` is the first byte NOT copied). This means

- the position of the null terminator is not initialized
- the string is possibly not correctly terminated

BTW, if you can, using [`asprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf) is safe, easy and fool-proof way of doing many string-manipulation tasks, although it may be a little less effective.